# How can I store input into an array permanently after my code ends?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is the array **nameData** and I want to know if there is some way to save the user's input into the given array even after my code is finished running. I guess that this reflects upon what i do in my free time...

```
var nameData = ["Nik"];
var Name = prompt("PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME:");
if (Name !== null){
 alert("Hello " + Name + "!");
nameData.push(Name); 
} 

for (var i = 0; i < nameData.length; i++) {
console.log(nameData[i]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with " even after my code is finished running"?

Comment: Write your name on your screen so it will be there even when the computer is off. Or you could think of one of the endless possibiltes of storing data

Comment: what I want is to be able to do is enter a name and it be sent up to the array so that I don't have to manually put names in the array.

Comment: ^ That's an even more confusing question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code that runs in JavaScript it not persistent. Once the program is finished, all values in memory are discarded. You need to save the value to disk or store it in a database using a server-side language.

You can export the array with:

```
var savedFile_JsonStringData = JSON.stringify(nameData);
```

and store its string contents in a file or database.

Then, to import the data, load the saved file and convert its string representation back into an array:

```
var nameData = JSON.parse(savedFile_JsonStringData);
```

---

## Local Storage

As others have noted, a temporary storage method may work if you don't need the data to hang around for too long.

[Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) offers the following:

> *The `sessionStorage` property allows you to access a session [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) object. `sessionStorage` is similar to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.localStorage), the only difference is while data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration set, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated.*

### Minimum browser version support

```
Feature        | Chrome | Firefox | IE | Opera | Safari
---------------+--------+---------+----+-------+-------
localStorage   | 4      | 3.5     | 8  | 10.50 | 4
sessionStorage | 5      | 2       | 8  | 10.50 | 4
```

### Example

```js
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('myKey', JSON.stringify(nameData));

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var nameData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('myKey'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something called session storage .

```
sessionStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(myArray));
//and to retrieve 
myArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("key"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but it sounds like you're making some kind of app or tool for yourself, and you'd like to keep a persistent state. For this, you can use the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

```
window.localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(nameData));
nameData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('names'));
```